# Portal doesn't look to above the Nether ceiling

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a problem because I want the nether portal to teleport me to a portal I made on the roof of the nether, and for that I went to the nether, destroyed the nether portal and created the new portal on the roof. and I teleported to where I wanted, but I went back and instead of teleporting to the portal that creates teleport me to a new one
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Overworld portals never bring you to portals that are above the Nether ceiling.
The best you could do would be to either…
- abuse one of the many bedrock breaking bugs and then place the portal two blocks lower than you normally could (so that the lowest portal block is on the same level as the highest bedrock blocks), then it can link normally, or…
- put the portal just under the top bedrock and set up two minecarts to quickly get up. One of them has to be directly below the top level bedrock and in a configuration where dismounting it puts your head inside that bedrock block, the other one is on top of the bedrock ceiling. To go up, just enter the lower minecart, exit it again and quickly jump and enter the upper minecart to take as little suffocation damage as possible.